# iPhone app facebook post to wall uses random "Share" app

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-wall

I'm doing a standard post to wall using iphone facebook sdk. The problem is that when I do the post, the wall post links to a generic app called "Share" instead of my app.

This is the app it is linking to
https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=206749070441

I'm providing my app key/secret to the SDK so I don't see why it is doing this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your wallpost code? That might be of help...

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely what you provided for your app's name when you created your key/secret.

To edit it, after you have logged in to Facebook goto: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

You should see a list of your apps, and can edit them there...

Comment: I am definitely using the correct key/secret. Here's another weird thing: it works correctly in other parts of the world and shows "Share" app here in the U.S.!

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you aren't using the correct key/secret. When you created you key/secret you also named your app. What did you call it? I am willing to bet you called is "Share".

Comment: No its named correctly. Its odd that it is working correctly in some places and not others. Sounds like a Facebook localization bug or something.